# How to replace an IMG with a smaller IMG but without messing up the style

Tags: html, image

I am dynamically creating HTML code out of C#.

What I want is: replace each IMG-Tag with a smaller IMG-File (which is a loading-gif). But: the whole style/Layout should remain the same (as the HTML-File I am loading is completely dynamic and could contain anything.

So a sample:

```html
<img alt="" src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/rectangle-in-wpf/Images/RectI.gif" height="100" width="100">

<span>Geographie</span>

<img alt="" src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/rectangle-in-wpf/Images/RectI.gif" height="100" width="100">

<span>Geschichte</span>

<img alt="" src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/rectangle-in-wpf/Images/RectI.gif" height="100" width="100">

<span>Gesellschaft</span>

<img alt="" src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/rectangle-in-wpf/Images/RectI.gif" height="100" width="100">
```

Several Images in a Row. Now I want to replace one of them (here: number 3) with a smaller image (here: a smiley) but: I want to have the same layout. So I tried this: Create a container which has the same size of the original Image and then I created the small image in it.

My problem is: As I am using DIV, it does a line break...

```html
<img alt="" src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/rectangle-in-wpf/Images/RectI.gif" height="100" width="100">

<span>Geographie</span>

<img alt="" src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/rectangle-in-wpf/Images/RectI.gif" height="100" width="100">

<span>Geschichte</span>

<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color:red;display: flex; ">
  <img alt="" src="https://affinity.serif.com/forum/public/style_emoticons/default/smile.png" height="20" width="20" style="margin: auto;">
</div>

<span>Gesellschaft</span>

<img alt="" src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/rectangle-in-wpf/Images/RectI.gif" height="100" width="100">
```

How can I solve this?

I really am looking for replacing only the -tag with something that has the same dimension/properties and can contain another image...

Comment: Can you not just make the loading gif image the same size as the other image but the actual loader to be small.

Comment: `display:inline-flex; vertical-align:bottom` on the div should do it.

Comment: I could create dynamically new GIF's with the same size. But that is too slow.

Comment: Hm CBroe that seems to fix it in the sample I gave.

I am just about to test it with my real HTML files. But thanks !

Comment: CBroe you saved me a lot of work - it's working perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your container is causing a line break is because divs default to have a style of "display:block;"

You can fix this by changing the display style to inline-block. You'll then want to make sure it's aligned properly with "vertical-align: top;"

See fixed snippet:

```html
<img alt="" src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/rectangle-in-wpf/Images/RectI.gif" height="100" width="100">

<span>Geographie</span>

<img alt="" src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/rectangle-in-wpf/Images/RectI.gif" height="100" width="100">

<span>Geschichte</span>

<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color:red; display: inline-block; vertical-align:top; ">
  <img alt="" src="https://affinity.serif.com/forum/public/style_emoticons/default/smile.png" height="20" width="20" style="margin: auto;">
</div>

<span>Gesellschaft</span>

<img alt="" src="http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/UploadFile/mahesh/rectangle-in-wpf/Images/RectI.gif" height="100" width="100">
```

Comment: _"The reason your container is causing a line break is because divs default to have a style of display:block;"_ - well, `display:flex` in the given example, to be exact. But that causes the same "line-breaking" behavior, of course. But I guess `flex` was used to get the smaller image to center automatically. Therefor, simply using `inline-flex` might be a bit more straight-forward than trying to get the image to center using different means.

Comment: @CBroe I agree your solution is better. You commented as I was writing mine. I didn't even realize inline-flex was a valid option. Thanks for teaching me a thing!